# ReverseManyToOne create object from children through django form

Tags: django, python-3.x, foreign-keys, relationship

Using:

Python 3.7.3

django 2.2.5

mysql 5.7.27

I have the following models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
...

class Comments(models.Model):
    Item = models.ForeignKey('Item', default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Comment = models.TextField(max_length=512, default="", blank=True)
```

I would like to create a *Comments* object, when creating the *Item* through a django form. I tried to do:

```
class ItemInsertForm(forms.ModelForm):
...

    Comments = forms.CharField(required=False,
                              widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':"Use comments to describe item details \
                                                                         or issues that other users should know",
                                                           'rows':5,
                                                           'cols':50,
                                                           }
                                                    )
                              )

    def clean_Comments(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _comment = self.cleaned_data.get('Comments')
        _comments = Item.comments_set.create(Comment=_comment)
        return _comments
```

but I get the following error:

> 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'create'

Both tables are empty, so no Item and no Comments currently exist. I guess that's why there is no 'create' method available. Is there a way I could achieve what I want?

Or is there another way to manage the comments for the *Item* object? I created another table to be able to associate multiple comments to the same item and differentiate between them. A character field in the *Item* class would concatenate all comments in a single string.

Answer (score 0):

I see quite some issues with your code, but since I feel like you gave it an honest shot, I'll try to help you out as best as I can.

First of all your models.py file:

- Model names should be singular, so instead of `Comments`, use `Comment`.
- Class members should be lowercase, so `Item` and `Comment` should be changed to `item` and `comment`.
- `Comment.comment` is still not very descriptive. The comment is the actual object, it's content is the text within the comment, so `text` would be more appropriate here.
- A ForeignKey with `null=True` already sets default to None.

Taking this into account and cleaning up your models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
...

class Comment(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=512, default="", blank=True)
```

---

Then, moving on to your form:

- Since it's a form for creation `Comments`, a more appropriate name would be `CommentForm`.
- `def clean_Comments(self, *args, **kwargs):` is a function reserved for doing validation on the `Comments` field, not for creating an object from the form input. For that you can use the ModelForm's [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method. You only need to define a save method if you're going to perform some custom logic though.

Let's fix those issues first, before I move onto the error message your getting:

```
class ItemInsertForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text']

    text = forms.CharField(required=False,
                              widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':"Write your comment to describe item details \
                                                                         or issues that other users should know",
                                                           'rows':5,
                                                           'cols':50,
                                                           }
                                                    )
                              )
```

This form, when submitted, will create a `Comment` object. However, there is still no ability to add the comment to an `Item`.

---

To do this, you need to make sure there are `Item` instances in the database, or allow the user to create one through an `ItemForm`
There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Add a `ModelChoiceField` to the CommentForm, which will allow the user to select an item from a select.

```
  item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.object.all(),
                                  to_field_name = '<item_name>',
                                  empty_label="Select an Item")
```

2. When you want to add this form to an something like an ItemDetailPage, you can use the currently viewed Item using something like

```
  item = Item.objects.get(pk=<item_id>)
```

or

```
  item = Item.objects.create(<item_properties_here>)
```

then, when saving your form:

```
  comment = form.save()
  comment.item = item.
  comment.save()
```

3. The third way is what you were trying, and why you were getting an error. Retrieve an item, then add the comment saved from the form to the item.comment_set.

   Something like this:

```
  item = Item.objects.get(pk=<item_id>)
  comment = form.save()
  item.comments_set.add(comment)
  item.save()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for tanking the time to answer, you have some good points. ItemInsertForm is not a form for adding comments, is a form for creating Items, but I wanted the possibility to also add Comments through this. I have actually acomplished what I wanted through the form_valid method from the view, by adding: item.comments_set.create(Comment=_comment) after I save the form., where _comment is form.cleaned_data.get('Comments').